# how to do this animation on img element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at CSS and I wanted to code an image animation in which the image starts appearing from the bottom right corner until the top left corner.

I couldn't do the animation on the image itself, I ended up adding a div element with the same background-color above the image

would anyone please teach me how to do the animation in a more professional way without using the div?

I don't mind if the code was using pure CSS or JS.

here is the code I wrote:

```css
.personal-photo {
  padding: 4rem;
  z-index: -10;
}

.photo-effect {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 42%;
  top: 91px;
  left: 91px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 300%;
  animation: photoEffect 2s infinite;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes photoEffect {
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="personal-photo" alt="">
  <div class="photo-effect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only the image if you consider mask:

```css
.personal-photo {
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#0000 50%,#000 0)
    0 0/200% 200% no-repeat;
  animation: photoEffect 1s linear forwards
}


@keyframes photoEffect {
  100% {
    -webkit-mask-position: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="personal-photo" alt="">
```

Answer (score -1):

I added some modifications to your code, is this what you are expecting?

```css
.personal-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.box::after {
    content: "";
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 325% 100%;
    background-position: 0%;
    animation: photoEffect 2s linear forwards;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}

@keyframes photoEffect {
    100% {
        background-position: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <img
           src="https://placekitten.com/200/300"
           class="personal-photo"
           alt=""/>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but the image disappears after the animation is over when removing infinite and alternate. I just want the animation to run once revealing the image behind the backgroung.

Comment: Once the animation is finished the background-position property resets back to 0%, so now the image is covered by the white background. If you want to maintain the animation end state you can use the forwards keyword in animation. Check the answer now. To learn more about forwards refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode @Marya